# Microstrategy documents - changing the kind of graph in Graph matrix

Tags: document, microstrategy

I inserted a graph matrix in my document but I cannot understand how to chang the kind of graph I want to see.

in the documentation (http://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/9.3/WebUser/WebHelp/Lang_1033/formatting_a_graph_matrix_visualization.htm) is written:

> From the **Shape** drop-down list, select the shape to use to display graph elements in the visualization.

But I cannot find this **Shape** drop-down list.

---

my proprerty menu look like this:

[image: proprerty menu]

By the way I dont want to change the kind of item shown in a graph (square, circle), I want to change the kind of graph (line chart, pie chart, scatter chart).

Comment: the page you linked is related to visual insight, the graph matrix in a document can be done with a widget (now deprecated), another way is to create a [Dashboard with a graph matrix](http://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/9.3/WebUser/WebHelp/Lang_1033/creating_a_graph_matrix_visualization.htm) and then [convert it into a document](http://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/9.5/WebUser/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Converting_analysis_into_document.htm)

Comment: I did it in the fist base, but after i converted my dashboard into a document the need for a new grid graph came, so I inserted it but it set to line graph and i cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this option in the properties?

[image]